# IntelliJ Java inspection: can one disable warnings re. parameter names identical to field names for setters?

Tags: intellij-idea

For Java setters we are typically using the same name as the field value as parameter name, e.g. like so:

```
    public void setMaxNrIterations(int maxNrIterations) {
        this.maxNrIterations = maxNrIterations;
    }
```

Obviously this causes warnings in IntelliJ since the field name and the parameter name are identical. Thus my colleagues tend to silence these warnings with an annotation `@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")` which I find most annoying and superfluous. The warning as such is valuable in general - so we certainly don't want to disable it - but setters are an exception to that rule!

Can't one silence that particular warning (for setters only!) in IntelliJ (as one can in Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this inspection does not trigger because of the name of the parameter. It reports method parameters that always have the same constant value.

SameParameterValue is a short name for "Method parameter is always the same value"

There are few thing you can setup for the inspection: maximal reported visibility, minimal reported usage count, as well as severity. You can find it in Preferences | Editor | Inspections Java | Declaration redundancy | Method parameter is always the same value

You can't exclude setters from this inspection. But setters are usually public, and inspection do not trigger on them with the default settings (maximal reported visibility == Protected)